# JMS and JPA transactions without two phase commit (i.e. JTA is not supported)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I am migrating a Spring boot app running on a JEE app server which makes use of JTA to coordinate JMS and JPA transactions:

- Exceptions raised while processing a message trigger a JPA and JMS roll-backs (i.e. message goes back to the originating queue)
- If all database operations are successful, and, the message is successfully moved to the next queue, JPA and JMS transactions are both committed

The target environment **does not support JTA**.

I am looking for guidance on how to setup transaction managers so that:

- a JPA transaction is started immediately after starting the JMS transaction
- a JPA transaction is concluded just before terminating the JMS transaction
- a failure of terminating the JPA transaction would fail the JMS transaction

Any documentation or sample code would be awesome.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: WIth 2 individual transaction managers there is no garantueed way. Why wouldn't the target support JTA? You can include something like atomikos in your app which handles the JTA stuff that way it is part of your application and not dependend on the environment you are deploying in.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , The target JMS provider does not support JTA. Regards

Comment: Atomikos allows for 1 non JTA resource to participate in a JTA transaction, it will automatically compensate for that.

Comment: "The target JMS provider does not support JTA." Then the target JMS provider does not actually support JMS, either.  Is this Spring Boot?  It would be helpful to know what the target environment might be.

Comment: The JMS provider supports is Azure ServiceBus premium. It supports JMS 2.0 but not JTA. The app is a Spring boot app.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way forward for this scenario where none of the resources support XA or JTA:

- JMS provider
- Database driver

... is to use a "bracketing" transaction manager configured to run two transactions. At high level, steps are as specified in [Dave Syer's article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html)

1. Start messaging transaction
2. Receive message
3. Start database transaction
4. Update database
5. Commit database transaction
6. Commit messaging transaction

The [Spring Data project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) provides such a transaction manager: see [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html) .

This strategy works well when the error occurs in committing the database transaction, i.e. step 5. For cases where the error happens in the JMS commit, i.e. step 6, one will end up with the message in dead-letter.

Testing this implementation with 100,000 messages showed that about 0.005 % message end up in dead letter. For some, the error occurred when committing the JPA transaction, some for JMS.

For the system to be operable, messages in dead-letter should be retriable *regardless of the point of failure*. This means that the *bracketing transaction manager* option is only viable if the app is changed to implement **idempotency**: keep a trace of the JMS Message IDs already processed. The app has to skip the update part, step 4, for when the JMS Message ID was already processed.